# c# surfing the web with vpn

Tags: c#, networking, proxy, vpn

im thinking on building a simple software, that can I surf the web with,
using the `WebBrowser` object. but, making sure that im under a vpn or proxy.

im wondering if it is even possible, to connect to a vpn or proxy service with some api 
and, get a new ip every an hour or time i choose.

if its possible, can u give me some refrences?
like, what do i need to learn to achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite simple, here's an example to get you started with the WebBrowser control,  you can have this up in minutes. [Web Browser Example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/59025-create-a-webbrowser/)

After this you're just adding the logic for your VPN or proxy, which is completely dependent on which you choose.

This might help if you're trying to not affect the system settings for IE: [Proxy Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499568/how-to-set-a-proxy-for-webbrowser-control-without-effecting-the-system-ie-proxy)

Although if you can, it's likely easier to just set them in the registry if you don't mind affecting IE. This on changing the registry: [Proxy Settings in the Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393713/enabling-disabling-proxy-app-doesnt-work-properly-with-ie)

As far as information specific to how to obtain a proxy, authentication, etc, you'll need to pick a proxy service you want to use and read up on them.  That should simply be a search engine research project.

Comment: thank u for the link. can u give me a link to VPN or proxy logic that u know about? that have an explanation on the steps that it need to take to connect to a service and use in?