# Refresh internet options on Windows in Java

Tags: java, windows, proxy, registry, refresh

I need to refresh internet options after changing network configuration via registry on Windows (Vista, 7 or 8). At the moment, when I modify the proxy configuration (via Advapi32), I need to restart a browser to have the modifications applied.

I found that I need to notify the system, in C# :
InternetSetOption(NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, NULL, 0);
InternetSetOption(NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, NULL, 0);

Related question : [Enabling/disabling proxy app doesn't work properly with IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393713/enabling-disabling-proxy-app-doesnt-work-properly-with-ie)

I need to do this simply in Java, is a way to do this without generating JNA classes/structs/enum of Wininet ? I think about Advapi32 which is native in JNA for example or a command line to execute by System.exec ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will solve the problem of having to restart the browser, but you can use the [`netsh` command with the `winhttp` option](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731131%28WS.10%29.aspx) to change the HTTP proxy settings on Windows.