# Call DLL function from command line with zero int pointers

Tags: c#, function, pointers, dll, cmd

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2025672/3397116), I would like to make this C# method call, but from the command line:

```
InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, 39, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

My attempt (from CMD):

```
rundll32.exe,InternetSetOption(0,39,0,0)
```

Unfortunately, this leads to an error (translated: `Problem while starting: wrong parameter`):

[image]

How can I make this DLL function call? What is the CMD equivalent of the C# `IntPtr.Zero`?

Comment: There is no IntPtr.Zero from the command line. Is rundll32.exe written by you? Alternatively run from PowerShell instead of CMD.

Comment: rundll32.exe is a standard application which gives you the opportunity to run functions from DLLs. Not written by me ;). How would it work from PowerShell?

Comment: rundll32.exe works only if the DLL implements a specific interface. InternetSetOption does not implement this interface. You would need to write a script - have you looked at this? https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/command-line-proxy-tool-with-c-source/

Comment: Thanks! Not a solution, but a good enough workaround. Served my purposes.