# How to programmatically set the proxy username and password in IE?

Tags: c#

How can I programmatically set the proxy username and password in IE using C#.
The problem is it asks me everytime, I open an IE instance and start browsing a page.

Comment: I'm betting it depends on the kind of proxy and its authentication mechanism. Can you provide more details ? I also bet http://superuser.stackexchange.com should be a better place for this question

Comment: Why don't you put the details in the 'Tools -> Internet Options' once and just forget it?

Comment: @Neeta - I want to do it programmaticaly.

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197725/programmatically-set-browser-proxy-settings-in-c-sharp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417685/programmatically-set-proxy-address-port-user-password-throught-windows-regist

Comment: @Kangkan - i have gone through that link but none of the solution given over ther works.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the registry entry like this

```
RegistryKey registry = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
registry.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
registry.SetValue("ProxyServer", "user:password@127.0.0.1:8080");
```

This works with IE only and Firefox does not work with this.

Comment: it does not works have you tested it before giving the answer.