# How do I request a xml page and parse through it without actually loading it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

From within my .aspx page I am trying to make a request to an xml page that is on the web and return the value of one of the nodes. The page in question will be a service that accepts a query string and outputs the results to my own aspx page.

For learning purposes though I am just trying to make a simple example. I have found this page: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml What I would like to do is have a button that when clicked will display to a textbox the value of the  < body>< /body> node?

I have been trying to do it with the WebClient Class but I'm not positive if this is the correct way to go about it. I have been following this example http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=33798 but I am encountering exception (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  It is like asking: How can I read a chapter without a book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ to XML like so to load the XML and retrieve the elements you wish:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml");
string xml = document.Root.ToString();
```

Using your example (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml), the above would output the following:

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit (Based on comment)**

If you are sitting behind a proxy server and have default credentials setup you can try the following (untested as not behind proxy):

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml");
webRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(streamReader.ReadToEnd()));
        string xml = document.Root.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(xml);
    }
}
```

**Note**

(From MSDN [WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy.aspx))

> The DefaultWebProxy property reads proxy settings from the app.config
>   file. If there is no config file, the current user's Internet Explorer
>   (IE) proxy settings are used.

Comment: Thanks this is what I am trying to accomplish. When I use the code above I get thrown the exception: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

Comment: @Curtis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197725/programmatically-set-browser-proxy-settings-in-c

Answer (score 0):

I think you can load the XML into an XmlDataDocument like this:

```
XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDataDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("http://mydomain.com/exportsearch?param=SearchText");
```

Once you have the XML in the document, it should be fairly easy to query it.