# Set system proxy

Tags: vb.net, proxy

Where might I find a way in Visual Basic .NET for setting the system proxy.

I want to set a check on a proxy server. Then set the system proxy to that proxy server.

I can't seem to find any place with information on doing this.

Comment: This is a vague recollection - but I seem to recall that the system gets its proxy settings from Internet Explorer.

Comment: Do you need it for your application? Or for other applications? There is [HttpWebRequest.Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx) and for system settings you should probably consider [using a group policy](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5156.how-to-force-proxy-settings-via-group-policy.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The following class will set the system proxy. I did not write it myself, and cant for the life of me remember where i found it:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices


Public Class IEProxy

Public Enum Options

    INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS = 1

    INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER = 2

    INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS = 3

    INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_URL = 4

    INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTODISCOVERY_FLAGS = 5

    INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH = 37

    INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION = 75

    INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED = 39

    PROXY_TYPE_PROXY = &H2

    PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT = &H1

End Enum


<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Private Class FILETIME

    Public dwLowDateTime As Integer

    Public dwHighDateTime As Integer

End Class


<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size:=12)> _
Private Structure INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION

    <FieldOffset(0)> Dim dwOption As Integer

    <FieldOffset(4)> Dim dwValue As Integer

    <FieldOffset(4)> Dim pszValue As IntPtr

    <FieldOffset(4)> Dim ftValue As IntPtr


    Public Function GetBytes() As Byte()

        Dim b(12) As Byte

        BitConverter.GetBytes(dwOption).CopyTo(b, 0)

        Select Case dwOption

            Case (Options.INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS)

                BitConverter.GetBytes(dwValue).CopyTo(b, 4)

            Case (Options.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS)

                BitConverter.GetBytes(pszValue.ToInt32()).CopyTo(b, 4)

            Case (Options.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER)

                BitConverter.GetBytes(pszValue.ToInt32()).CopyTo(b, 4)

        End Select

        Return (b)

    End Function

End Structure


<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Class INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST

    Public dwSize As Integer

    Public pszConnection As String

    Public dwOptionCount As Integer

    Public dwOptionError As Integer

    Public pOptions As IntPtr

End Class

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Private Class INTERNET_PROXY_INFO

    Public dwAccessType As Integer

    Public lpszProxy As IntPtr

    Public lpszProxyBypass As IntPtr

End Class


Private Const ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122

Private Const INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY = 38

Private Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT = 1


<DllImport("wininet.dll")> _
Private Shared Function InternetSetOption(ByVal hInternet As IntPtr, _
               ByVal dwOption As Integer, _
               ByVal lpBuffer As INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST, _
               ByVal dwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean

End Function


<DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetLastError() As Integer

End Function


Public Function SetProxy(ByVal proxy_full_addr As String) As Boolean

    Dim bReturn As Boolean

    Dim list As New INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST

    Dim dwBufSize As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(list)

    Dim opts(3) As INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION

    Dim opt_size As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(opts(0))


    list.dwSize = dwBufSize

    list.pszConnection = ControlChars.NullChar

    list.dwOptionCount = 3


    'set flags

    opts(0).dwOption = Options.INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS

    opts(0).dwValue = Options.PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT Or Options.PROXY_TYPE_PROXY


    'set proxyname

    opts(1).dwOption = Options.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER

    opts(1).pszValue = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(proxy_full_addr)


    'set override

    opts(2).dwOption = Options.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS

    opts(2).pszValue = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local")


    Dim b(3 * opt_size) As Byte

    opts(0).GetBytes().CopyTo(b, 0)

    opts(1).GetBytes().CopyTo(b, opt_size)

    opts(2).GetBytes().CopyTo(b, 2 * opt_size)


    Dim ptr As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(3 * opt_size)

    Marshal.Copy(b, 0, ptr, 3 * opt_size)


    list.pOptions = ptr

    'Set the options on the connection

    bReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, Options.INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, list, dwBufSize)

    If Not bReturn Then

        Debug.WriteLine(GetLastError)

    End If


    'Notify existing Internet Explorer instances that the settings have changed

    bReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, Options.INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, Nothing, 0)

    If Not bReturn Then

        Debug.WriteLine(GetLastError)

    End If


    'Flush the current IE proxy setting

    bReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, Options.INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, Nothing, 0)

    If Not bReturn Then

        Debug.WriteLine(GetLastError)

    End If


    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(opts(1).pszValue)

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(opts(2).pszValue)

    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr)

    Return (bReturn)

End Function


Public Function DisableProxy() As Boolean

    Dim bReturn As Boolean

    Dim list As New INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST

    Dim dwBufSize As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(list)

    Dim opts(0) As INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION

    Dim opt_size As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(opts(0))


    list.dwSize = dwBufSize

    list.pszConnection = ControlChars.NullChar

    list.dwOptionCount = 1


    opts(0).dwOption = Options.INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS

    opts(0).dwValue = Options.PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT


    Dim b(opt_size) As Byte

    opts(0).GetBytes().CopyTo(b, 0)


    Dim ptr As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(opt_size)

    Marshal.Copy(b, 0, ptr, opt_size)


    list.pOptions = ptr

    'Set the options on the connection

    bReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, Options.INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, list, dwBufSize)

    If Not bReturn Then

        Debug.WriteLine(GetLastError)

    End If


    'Notify existing Internet Explorer instances that the settings have changed

    bReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, Options.INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, Nothing, 0)

    If Not bReturn Then

        Debug.WriteLine(GetLastError)

    End If


    'Flush the current IE proxy setting

    bReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, Options.INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, Nothing, 0)

    If Not bReturn Then

        Debug.WriteLine(GetLastError)

    End If


    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr)

    Return (bReturn)

End Function


End Class
```

to use:

```
Dim sProxy As New IEProxy
'set
sProxy.SetProxy("123.2.2.123:8080") 'Returns True if successful
'disable
sProxy.DisableProxy 'Returns True if successful
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [Programmatically Set Browser Proxy Settings in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197725/programmatically-set-browser-proxy-settings-in-c-sharp)?

It covers changing global proxy for your application and changing system settings as well.