# Trying to edit the proxy enabled registry key

Tags: c#

I cannot figure out how to turn the Web Proxy off when I close the console. My current code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           RegistryKey inetproxyRegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true); 
            inetproxyRegKey.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 0);
   }
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem you are having is? Does the code execute?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically Set Browser Proxy Settings in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197725/programmatically-set-browser-proxy-settings-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*
            Your Code here
            */


            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit);

        }
        static private void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegistryKey inetproxyRegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
            inetproxyRegKey.SetValue("ProxyEnable",1);

        }
```