# Is it possible to set and unset the autoproxy (WPAD) and "apply" the configuration to the system?

Tags: c#, winapi, proxy

I need to set an automatic configuration script that will set the proxy.

When I do this through the LAN settings, all is ok and Chrome is aware of the change immediately. I tried to replicate this behavior by changing the registry key `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` -> `AutoConfigURL` but Chrome is aware of the change only several minutes after the change (not sure why).

My next attempt is to use Winapi, but I cannot find how to set this script. I found the read function [`WinHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpdetectautoproxyconfigurl) that works well, but I cannot find a write equivalent.

How do I setup the autoproxy script with Winapi?

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer (only for the setup of the autoproxy). After the registry modification, [`InternetInitializeAutoProxyDll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetinitializeautoproxydll) must be called.

Here is a sample code:

```cs
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int InternetInitializeAutoProxyDll(uint dwReserved);

// ...

registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", true);

// Setup the registry value:
registryKey.SetValue("AutoConfigURL", "http://the/config/path");

// Tell Windows to initialize the proxy:
if (InternetInitializeAutoProxyDll(0) == 0)
{
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

However, it does not work when the proxy is unset:

```cs
registryKey.DeleteValue(AutomaticProxyRegistryName);

// Does nothing:
if (InternetInitializeAutoProxyDll(0) == 0)
{
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fiddling directly with the registry I recommend to do everything through the [WinINet API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wininet/wininet-reference). See [Programmatically Set Browser Proxy Settings in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197725/programmatically-set-browser-proxy-settings-in-c-sharp) for info on how to do this using C#. Code mentioned in that question can also be found [here](https://github.com/131/proxytoggle).

**EDIT**

The example mentioned fiddles with the registry, too. I have [uploaded](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoIYSOG_AJ2Rux-ml-eicpeKMG1g) parts of a program that show how to do everything using WinINet calls. Unfortunately the program is written in Delphi, so you might have to translate it to C#. What is important is that one always resets the proxy settings before setting new values.