# vm behind proxy and module installation by pipeline task

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, virtual-machine

A windows vm is configured that is residing the proxy and I can get the response from the VM's admin powershell prompt with the following command:

```
Get-PSRepository
```

But if I issue the very same command inside the Azure Devops pipeline I get the following instead:

```
WARNING: MSG:UnableToDownload «https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409» «»
WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your internet connection.
WARNING: Unable to find module repositories.
Finishing: PowerShell
```

I can check and get the proxy settings though from the powershell in the pipeline with the following command:

```
netsh winhttp show proxy
```

Comment: Hi @sajis997 Did you try setting the proxy for your powershell task as below answer pointed out. how did it go?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are hosting a self-host agent on the windows VM. Some tools will not automatically use the agent configured proxy settings as stated in the document [Run a self-hosted agent behind a web proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#how-the-agent-handles-the-proxy-within-a-build-or-release-job).

You can try setting an environmental variable as below at the beginning of the your powershell command to specifically set the proxy for your powershell task.

```
$env:http_proxy = "192.3.4.5:8080"
```

Please refer to this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55942362/azure-pipelines-agent-proxy-settings-not-working-as-expected/55959449). If above script to set proxy env variable doesnot work, you can try command `Set-InternetProxy -Proxy test:8080` in this [blog](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-function-Get-cba2abf5).